# how to solve javafx table-view focused problem?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, styling, javafx-css

I have a problem in javafx `table view` focused problem. This is my `table view` when `unfocused` as shown in figure.

[image]

The `table view` when `focused`:

[image]

But when i am outside of the table view and click `show-hide-column` button the table does not get focused

[image]

how to solve this problem using css if possible. or any other tricks....???

Comment: Where is the button? Is it outside of the `TableView`? Why do you need the `TableView` to be focused? What is the button supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry! for confusion! Actualy, I have pressed table view show-hide-column button. I have apply css and remove + button in my table view.... As shown in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqs3H.png